# Super-energetic photon: thought experiment:

Tags: photons

Suppose a photon that had a wavelength so small that if its energy were changed to matter it would have enough mass to collapse in on itself to form a blackhole the size of the one at the center of our galaxy.

1. What is the approximate wavelength?
2. What would happen when it interacts with at atom?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just naively calculating the wavelength using $E=mc^2$ and $E=\frac{h c}{\lambda}$ using the mass of the milky way black hole?

Comment: ... and while you're calculating that value as per Triatticus's suggestion, be sure to compare your result against the [Planck length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units).